# Failed to download xcodegen from Homebrew on buddybuild

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, homebrew, buddy-build, xcodegen

We have our CI job running on buddybuild successfully for years. Today it failed suddenly with some errors like

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/xcodegen-2.20.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/xcodegen-2.20.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://github.com/-/v2/packages/container/package/homebrew%2Fcore%2Fxcodegen-2.20.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
Error: Failed to download resource "xcodegen"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/xcodegen-2.20.0.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
```

(We use xcodegen to generate the our iOS project/workspace.)
Searching online we found a similar post https://travis-ci.community/t/cannot-install-anything-from-homebrew/11445 but were not sure how to update homebrew on buddybuild. Any ideas will be highly appreciated.